# Como imprimir uma operação em Python adicionando zero a esquerda?

Tags: python

```
a = int(input('Número: '))
b = int(input('Número: '))
c = a / b
print(c)
```

Caso eu atribua  A = 10; B = 5

O print irá mostrar 2, gostaria de saber se existe algum tipo de format que me permita que o print mostre 02?

Obrigado.

Comment: Você quer exibir 02 para um número inteiro? E se sua divisão gerar um número real, como 2.5? O que você exibiria?

Comment: Perdão, minha pergunta foi mal redigida, confundi algumas coisas, agora está atualizada

Answer (score 5):

Se quiser que o `print()` saia com dois dígitos, como por exemplo `02`, pode-se utilizar a função [`.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting):

```
>>> c = 2
>>> print('{:02}'.format(c))
    02
```

O problema pontuado pelo @JeanExtreme002 é válido. Se passar um float, ex: `c = 2.3`, o resultado do `print()` será `2.3`.

Answer (score 4):

Formate a expressão em uma [`fstring`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals):

```
a = int(input('Número: '))
b = int(input('Número: '))
c = a / b

#define a largura mínima em 2 caracteres, preenchendo com 0 a direita
#remove ponto decimal se a mantissa for 0
print(f'{c:02g}')
```

Saída:

```
Número: 10
Número: 5
02
```

Referencia [Mini-linguagem de especificação de formato](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec).

Answer (score 2):

É impossível obter o valor `02` na forma de `float` ou `int`, pois em Python e até mesmo na sua própria calculadora, o valor `02` será convertido em só `2`.

Para acrescentar o zero à esquerda, você deverá transformar seu dado em string, concatenando `"0"` com o valor em string. Exemplo:

```
a = int(input('Número: '))
b = int(input('Número: '))
c = a / b

c = "0" + str(c) # Formata o valor

print(c)
```

Mas pense um pouco, o que aconteceria se o resultado fosse `5.7` por exemplo? Você gostaria que a formatação fosse `05.7`? Ficaria um pouco estranho não?

Há uma outra forma de formatar o valor e até melhor, que é utilizando o método de string [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting), dessa forma:

```
c = "{:02}".format(c)
```

A diferença entre a primeira forma que apresentei e essa, é que o zero é acrescentado somente se for necessário. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
c = 12

print("0" + str(c))       # 012
print("{:02}".format(c))  # 12
```

---

Observação: Você atualizou a sua pergunta trocando os valores de A e B, para dar a entender que só faria operações onde o resultado fosse inteiro. O problema é que em Python, todas as divisões retornam valores do tipo `float` .

Isso significa que realizando essa operação:

```
>>> 10 / 5
```

O resultado seria `2.0`. Se quiser retirar esse *ponto flutuante* do valor, você deverá convertê-lo para `int`, dessa forma:

```
int(10 / 5)
10 // 5 # É possível também utilizar "//" para divisões inteiras
```

Comment: Mano... porque negativaram a resposta agora? Fiquei bolado ;-;

Comment: Não sei quem te negativou ou porquê. Mas a sua resposta parece estar bem legal. +1 então.